# Convert Hexadecimal to Base64 in Authotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I just found this code written in python to convert Hexadecimal to Base64:

```
import codecs
hex = "10000000000002ae"
b64 = codecs.encode(codecs.decode(hex, 'hex'), 'base64').decode()
```

So, Is it possible to find same working one but in Autohotkey?

Answer (score 0):

There many implementations, some very fast and some more simple. You can take a look at [libcrypt.ahk](https://github.com/ahkscript/libcrypt.ahk) for many encoding and encryption algorithms including Hexadecimal and Base64.

If you do use it, you'll want to look at `LC_Hex2Bin()` and `LC_Base64_Encode()`. Examples are available too. You will likely want this [libcrypt.ahk](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ahkscript/libcrypt.ahk/master/build/libcrypt.ahk) file in particular.

### Example

```
#Include libcrypt.ahk

Hex := "48656c6c6f20576f726c642100"
len := LC_Hex2Bin(Bin, Hex)

LC_Base64_Encode(base64, Bin, len)

MsgBox % base64
```

Or as single function

```
#Include libcrypt.ahk

MsgBox % hexstring2base64("48656c6c6f20576f726c642100")

hexstring2base64(hex_string) {
    len := LC_Hex2Bin(Bin, hex_string)
    LC_Base64_Encode(base64, Bin, len)
    return base64
}
```

Comment: Really nice collections. Unfortunately, none of them converts hex to base64.

Comment: `LC_Hex2Bin()` converts to binary, and `LC_Base64_Encode()` converts binary to base64.